# How To Save Events From a Google Calendar External Source To My Own DB In Full Calendar On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, fullcalendar

So I currently have a calendar that is connected to my own DB full of events that can be edited. I can also view events from an external source on the calendar by  using

```
$('#calender').fullCalendar({

        googleCalendarApiKey: 'MY API KEY IS HERE',

        eventSources: [
            {
                googleCalendarId: 'en.new_zealand#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'
            },
            {
                googleCalendarId: 'en-gb.australian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
                className: 'nice-event'
            }
        ],
...
```

The only problem though is I want to save the events from these sources to my own DB so that they can be edited and saved.

If possible I would prefer it to be on a button click rather than in the main calendar section. So when the button is pressed I can grab the info from these sources and put it into my own DB so that I just display the data from my own DB on the calendar.

Everywhere online I have only found about how to save from full calendar to google calendar, not the other way around which is what I want.

Feel free to ask questions or point out where I have not been clear enough.

Comment: you can call the clientEvents method (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) anytime you like (e.g. on click of a button) you'll get all the events currently shown on the fullCalendar. Providing they contain enough of the info transposed from Google Calendar to suit your purpose, that might be sufficient as your data source. If not then you'll probably have to fetch data from the Google Calendar API directly yourself. The other thing to consider is that fullCalendar doesn't support recurring events, so anything using fullCalendar as the data source has lost that extra info

Comment: Yea I have tried using the clientEvents method but everyone online seems to be getting a list from it but I always get an object returned       

For example this       
**console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'))**       
returns an object that looks like this       
**m.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#calendar"}**       
instead of returning an array

Comment: I've never heard of that happening. What browser produced a log like that?
 Have you definitely got events displayed on the calendar at the time? What version of fullCalendar are you using?